# kpathsea: "I can't find file `ptmr8t+10'."

Tags: fonts, latexmk, metafont, times

Using latexmk 4.39 on Arch Linux, I get a compile error regarding "ptmr8t+10".
`tlmgr search --global --file ptmr8t` gives me the "times" package which is already installed but `tlmgr search --global --file ptmr8t+10` comes up empty. What exactly is happening there and how I can resolve this?

**Output tail of `latexmk paper.tex`**

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm ptmr8t+10
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for ptmr8t+10.
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ptmr8t+10
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2013)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf ptmr8t+10
! I can't find file `ptmr8t+10'.
<*> ...jfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ptmr8t+10

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...jfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ptmr8t+10

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: ptmr8t+10.log: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input ptmr8t+10' failed to make ptmr8t+10.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font csnameendcsname=ptmr8t+10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not 
found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.25 \begin{document}
```

Comment: This looks like you are using the `microtype` package, but running `latex` rather than `pdflatex`

Comment: Thanks, adding a pdf parameter `latexmk -pdf paper.tex` solved the issue!

Comment: For the googlers. Similar error and solution for `kpathsea: Running mktexmf clmr28t10+20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by `latexmk -pdf paper.tex` (thanks again, Andrew Swann!)